# Pimples: Causes and Cures?

Tags: prevention, acne

I am thirteen years old and have quite a few pimples. I have a couple of questions:

**1. What causes them?**

**2. When I pop them(I try not too) they ooze out sticky fluid. What is it?**

**3. How can I stop them? Every morning and night, I rinse my face, then     wash my face(with soap) and rinse again, then scrub with sugar, then put on some medicine.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put - skin cells, sebum and hair can clump together into a plug, this plug gets infected with bacteria, resulting in a swelling. A pimple starts to develop when the plug begins to break down.

According to Wikipedia: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pimples
“A pimple is a result of a blockage of the skin's pore. 
 Inside the pore are sebaceous glands which produce sticky sebum. When the outer layers of skin shed (as it does continuously), the dead skin cells left behind may become 'glued' together by the sticky sebum. This causes a blockage in the pore. The sebaceous glands produce more sebum which builds up behind the blockage, and this sebum harbours bacteria (P.Acnes bacteria). Since the body's natural defence against bacteria is primarily phagocytes (white blood cells), these rush to the site behind the blockage (where the bacteria are). This is what gives some pimples the 'whiteheads' (unless the Phagocytes are deeper in the skin, which means you can't see the 'white' caused by them). The white blood cells then destroy (by phagocytosis) the bacteria to prevent infection.”

Over-the-counter medications

Common over-the-counter medications for pimples are benzoyl peroxide and/or salicylic acid and antibacterial agents such as triclosan. Both medications can be found in many creams and gels used to treat acne (acne vulgaris) through topical application. Both medications help skin slough off more easily, which helps to remove bacteria faster. Before applying them the patient needs to wash his or her face with warm water and dry

Home-remedies

1. Dab some lemon juice on it

Lemon juice can help get rid of breakouts for a number of reasons. It is rich in vitamin C, which is good for all types of skin, and it’s a citric acid, so it helps ‘exfoliate’ the skin as well. Most importantly though, it is an astringent. An astringent will cause a contraction of body tissues, and will therefore dry out the blemish itself.

2. The land of milk and honey (or yogurt)

The reason it is suggested that milk would cause acne is because of the extra hormones in it-but unless it’s ingested, this doesn’t really do much. For the most part, it just soothes the irritated skin, and helps tone down the redness.

3. Whip up some ‘whites

Egg whites are an easy and affordable way to help reduce acne and fade scars left by unfortunate blemishes. The reason people have found egg whites to be helpful for their skin is because they’re chock full of proteins and vitamins that both combat acne, and help to rebuild your skin cells.

For more home-remedies and directions on how to apply them, visit:

http://everydayroots.com/acne-remedies

Comment: For the egg whites- do I eat them or put them on my face?

Comment: You put them on your face. For directions, check the site posted in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MNT](http://www.belmarrahealth.com/natural-remedies-for-adult-acne/), A pimple is a small pustule or papule. Pimples are small skin lesions or inflammations of the skin - they develop when sebaceous glands (oil glands) become clogged and infected, leading to swollen, red lesions filled with pus.

Pimples are also known as spots or zits

The development of pimples is primarily connected to oil production, dead skin cells, clogged pores and bacteria (although yeast infection can also cause pimples to develop)

Sebaceous glands, which are located at the base of hair follicles, can become overactive due to hormone dysregulation, which is why acne is most commonly associated with puberty, and why breakouts occur around the time of menses.

The most likely parts of the body to be affected by pimples are the face, back, chest and shoulders due to the proliferation of sebaceous glands in these areas of skin. Pimples are a sign of acne, especially when a breakout occurs.

**Herbal remedies for acne** ([Source](http://www.belmarrahealth.com/natural-remedies-for-adult-acne/))

Apple cider vinegar: Noted for promoting energy and good digestion, consider apple cider vinegar also has potent antibacterial and antifungal properties, helping to kill off acne-causing bacteria. It also balances pH levels in the skin, making it more difficult for bacteria to come back. Simply dilute a little with fresh water, pour onto a cloth and apply. Use once a day.

Green tea extract: Green tea is an all-round health hero. As the Mayo Clinic reports, a lotion of 2 percent green tea extract helped reduce acne in two studies of adolescents and young adults with mild to moderate acne. While no studies have been done with older adults, this could be an excellent addition to your natural remedies for acne.

Coconut oil: This healthy superfood is also soft and gentle on the skin. It can bring down acne redness and fight bacteria. Use just a little and see how your skin improves.

Zinc. This nutrient helps the immune system fight off invading bacteria and viruses. Zinc in natural lotions and creams may reduce acne breakouts.

Herbs are also a simple at-home remedy for acne that can be effective. We’d recommend trying these herbal remedies:

Aloe vera. The popular spiky green plant is one of the most commonly used herbs in America today. It’s used for soothing and healing burns, wounds and skin irritations, so include it in your herbal remedies for acne. Use aloe as a spot treatment on the infected areas to help bring down swelling and redness.

Tea tree oil: Tea tree oil is excellent for adult acne. Its antibacterial properties help to remove dead skin, cleanse pores and kill acne-causing bacteria. Combine a little with water to dilute it, or mix it with some aloe vera gel and apply on your skin. A word of caution: Never ingest it or get it in your eyes or nose.

Chasteberry, also known as vitex or monk’s pepper, was used by Hippocrates to treat injuries and inflammation. American Family Physician highlights a 2001 German study showing that chasteberry’s active ingredients can influence particular hormones, including those associated with hormonal acne. You can drink chasteberry tea or try the herb in capsule form.